# How to replace Spinner with UIProgress view?

Tags: c#, ios

I am relatively new to iOS Xamarin c# development.

I created an app for an iPad which on demand(button DownloadDocuments) downloads documents for offline use.
While download is in progress the "Loading overlay" is shown with the "spinner". The app is in use and everything works great...but.
Now the client wants to see a Progress bar instead of a spinner. 
The design is: Master-Detail controller, button is in master, downloading is performed by a procedure in "Utilities" class.

I've read so many posts in all kins of forums, but this Threading matter is still very much "terra Nova" to me.

I coded the UIProgressView into Loading overlay and I can see it, if I assign some 0.5f value to the Progress property. 
How do IO make the progress move?

Where(if I have to) do I invoke the new thread and progress value assignment:
- in Utilities.DounloadDocuments? 
- In the cycle of downloading files(I'm using WebClient)?
- In the button handler?

Could somebody help me, please.

Comment: I remember there were some problems with download progress on iOS, so first check if the download progress changed is triggered, if it is then you must have some problems with displaying progress bar. Check if it is triggered and reply.

Comment: I placed this code into Utilities.DownloadDocuments procedure     `code`myWebClient.DownloadProgressChanged+=delegate (
     object sender,DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
     {
      if(e.TotalBytesToReceive!=0)
      {
      objLoadOverlay.InvokeOnMainThread(()=>{
       objLoadOverlay.DownloadProgress.Progress = e.BytesReceived / e.TotalBytesToReceive;
       });
      }
     }; and no it is not triggered

Comment: If not then you can't track download progress this way. But check the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You would first need to add a class of type Progress and attach an event to the ProgessChanged Event. When that fires then you would set the "Progess" values of your UIProgressView.

```
Progress<DownloadBytesProgress> progress = new Progress<DownloadBytesProgress>();
            progress.ProgressChanged += (s, args) => UIProgressBar.Progress = args.PercentComplete;
```

Then in your download routine, after each chunk of data is downloaded you would set...

```
DownloadBytesProgress args = new DownloadBytesProgress(urlToDownload, receivedBytes, totalBytes);
                progess.Report(args);
```

You can see an example here...

[github download progress](https://github.com/xamarin/recipes/tree/master/cross-platform/networking/download_progress)

Comment: I followed your instructions but I got an error message on progress.Report(args) Error CS1061: Type `System.Progress<namespace.DownloadBytesProgress>' does not contain a definition for `Report' and no extension method `Report' of type `System.Progress<namespace.DownloadBytesProgress>' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference? (CS1061)

Comment: Ok, disregard the previous. The only problem now - progress bar is not moving(stays white) till the end of the download process.